# people detection and counting using opencv and yolov4 code but the code is not showing anything

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

Im working in project for people detection and counting using opencv and yolov4 but the code is not showing anything when i run it and immediately closed , i dont know if wrote something wrong or am i missing a thing , help me.

this is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Define the motion history time window in seconds
MOTION_HISTORY_TIME_WINDOW = 2.0

def detect_people(frame, net, classes, colors):
    height, width, channels = frame.shape
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)
    net.setInput(blob)
    outputs = net.forward(net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames())

    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    for output in outputs:
        for detection in output:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.5 and classes[class_id] == "person":
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)
                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)
                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append(confidence)

    return boxes, confidences

def main():
    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet("yolov4.cfg", "yolov4.weights")
    classes = []
    with open("coco.names", "r") as f:
        classes = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.0.103:8080/video")
    try:
        people_counter = 0

        # Initialize the motion history dictionary
        motion_history = {}

        while True:
            print("Reading frame...")
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if not ret:
                break
            print("Frame read successfully")
            print("Performing people detection...")
            boxes, confidences = detect_people(frame, net, classes, colors)

            if len(boxes) > 0:
                print("Drawing bounding boxes and updating people counter...")
                # Draw the bounding boxes and update the people counter
                for box, confidence in zip(boxes, confidences):
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, box, colors[np.argmax(confidence)], 2)

                    # Calculate the center position of the person
                    center_x, center_y = int(box[0] + box[2] / 2), int(box[1] + box[3] / 2)

                    # Calculate a unique identifier for this person
                    person_id = f"{center_x}:{center_y}"

                    # Update the motion history for this person
                    if person_id not in motion_history:
                        motion_history[person_id] = []
                    motion_history[person_id].append((center_x, center_y))

                    # Remove old positions from the motion history
                    motion_history[person_id] = motion_history[person_id][-int(np.ceil(MOTION_HISTORY_TIME_WINDOW / cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))):]

                    if len(motion_history[person_id]) == 1:
                        people_counter += 1

            # Display the output frame and the people counter
            cv2.putText(frame, f"People: {people_counter}", (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.imshow("People Counter", frame)

            # Exit the loop when the 'q' key is pressed
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

    finally:
        # Release the IP camera stream and destroy all windows
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

i added a print function to check my frame as :

```
 while True:
            print("Reading frame...")
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if not ret:
                break
            print("Frame read successfully")
            print("Performing people detection...")
```

i was waiting one of the print fuction work but non of it showed when i was running the code .

and this was the result :

> > > %Run peopleYOLO.py

i already installed yolov4.cfg,yolov4.weights
and i uninstalledthe packages and reinstalled it again
and nothing appeard , i change also  cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.0.103:8080/video") to a video path not url and the same problem .